# Android Partially Downloaded Files Report Wrong File Size

Tags: java, android, file-io, download

I'm putting together some code to download files from an HTTP address in Android. I'd like to support download resumption if the download fails mid way.

The output I get when starting the download, then killing the wifi connection and restarting again several times is the following:

Start size 0
Stop size 12333416
Start size 12333416
Stop size **16058200**
Start size **3724784**

I cannot understand why after the first resumption, subsequent file size readings of the partially downloaded file do not match.

Thanks in advance!

```
public void download(String source, String target) throws IOException {
    BufferedOutputStream outputStream = null;
    InputStream inputStream = null;

    try {
        File targetFile = new File(target);
        currentBytes = targetFile.length();

        Log.i(TAG, "Start size " + String.valueOf(currentBytes));
        outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(targetFile));

        // create the input stream
        URLConnection connection = (new URL(source)).openConnection();
        connection.setConnectTimeout(mCoTimeout);
        connection.setReadTimeout(mSoTimeout);

        inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
        inputStream.skip(currentBytes);

        // calculate the total bytes
        totalBytes = connection.getContentLength();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead;

        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            // write the bytes to file
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            outputStream.flush();

            currentBytes += bytesRead;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (outputStream != null) {
            // close the output stream
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
        }

        if (inputStream != null) {
            // close the input stream
            inputStream.close();
        }

        Log.i(TAG, "Stop size " + String.valueOf(currentBytes));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you are doing wrong:

1. To resume download to file you should append, not rewrite the file. Use special constructor for output stream:

   FileOutputStream(targetFile, true)
2. To request part of file from server you should use HTTP 1.1 property "Range". You can do it like this:

   HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
   connection.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=" + currentBytes + "-");